# Oracle SQL Todays Date from Data

Tags: sql, oracle

Apologies as I am extremely green within SQL.

I am currently trying to run the below:

```
SELECT * 
FROM test.message 
WHERE MESSAGESUBJECT LIKE '%test%'
AND MESSAGEDATE = CURRENT_DATE
```

However the results are not pulling back - figured this to be the fact the format of the data within the field currently looks like this:

```
07-MAR-19 08.13.53.00000000 PM
```

So the obvious solution is to get it to look at the start of the field - where I'm losing track is that I need the query for a job that's running daily so I cant use exacts. Anyone able to assist?

Thanks,

D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM test.message 
 where MESSAGESUBJECT like '%test%' 
 and MESSAGEDATE BETWEEN TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE) AND TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE) + 86399/86400
```

This will get rows where the message date was any time today.

The 86399/86400 bit is the number of seconds in a day minus 1, so it makes the `BETWEEN` range cover the whole day and none of the next day (which `TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE)+1` would do).

Instead of adding 86399/86400, some find it clearer to add a whole day and then subtract out an an `INTERVAL` of 1 second.  That also works, as does:

```
AND MESSAGEDATE >= TRUNC(SYSDATE)
AND MESSAGEDATE < TRUNC(SYSDATE)+1  -- Thanks @WernfriedDomscheit
```

Using

```
AND TRUNC(MESSAGEDATE) = TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE)
```

is logically correct, but it makes it impossible for Oracle to use an index on `MESSAGEDATE` if there is one, which can rob you of your best possible performance.  But if you have a function based index on `TRUNC(MESSAGEDATE)`, then that last way is also a reasonable option.

Comment: `MESSAGEDATE >= TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE) AND MESSAGEDATE < TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE) +1` is another option of doing it.

Comment: Thanks a bunch Matthew - works perfectly and extremely appreciate the breakdown!

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Thanks for the addition.  I prefer `BETWEEN` because it keeps the condition as a single expression in the predicate.  But that's just my taste/habit and I could easily imagine that I'm in the minority on that one.  I updated my answer based on your comment.  Thanks again.